# How to detect if axios exceeds timeout

Tags: javascript, axios, ipfs

Im currently working on `IPFS` and Im having this problem.

I have a list of `IPFS` hashes that I want to render it in the shortest time, that's why I need to find the most suitable gateways at every different times.
My idea is using recusion/loop to random the gateways in a list for every `IPFS` hash, if `axios` responds too long or catch error, it calls itself (go to the next gate way) until has a suitable gateway responding within time limit.

But I dont know how to detect if `axios` gets out because of timeout or get it successfully.

This is my code:

```
const publicGateway = [
    "https://ipfs.eth.aragon.network/ipfs/",
    "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/",
    "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/",
    "https://ipfs.fleek.co/ipfs/",
    "https://ipfs-infura.io/ipfs/",
    // ... more
]
```

```
export const findPublicGateWay = (ipfs) => {
    let url;

    const getGateway = async () => {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * publicGateway.length);
        url = publicGateway[random] + ipfs;    // get random urls

        try {
            await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: url,
                timeout: 2000,    // get out if the url does not respond after 2 seconds
            });

            /*
             * this block runs if the request exceeded timeout
             *
             * getGateway();    exceeds timeout: call itself
             * 
             */

            /*
             * this block runs if the request succeeded
             *
             * return url;    nothing: return url
             * 
             */


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            getGateway();    // catch error: call itself
        }
    }
    getGateway();
}
```

Or is there any better way for this case?

Im sorry because my code is a bit messy, thank you everyone, Im a learner so all your answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that catch section is suitable place to handle timeout errors. Also, you ought to check error.message or error.code in the catch section.